# ¿Cómo seleccionar una fila y mostrar los datos en un modal?

Tags: reactjs

Muy buenas estoy intentando mostrar los datos de una tabla en un modal y no puedo hacer que al seleccionar la fila abra el modal con todos los datos del ticket seleccionado en la tabla.

Estoy trabajando con boostrap 4 para  la parte visual y quiero usar una tabla normal.

Logre hacer lo que quiero con componentes como MuiDatatable o React-boostrap pero no quiero usar ese tipo de componentes

Asi traigo mis datos en el array data:

```
class TicketsContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL || 'https://localhost:5050';
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }


  getData() {
    Axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}/tickets`)
      .then(result => this.setState({ ...this.state, data: result.data }))
      .catch(error => alert(error.message));
  }
```

Aca mapeo los datos y los muestro en la tabla

```
{this.state.data.length && (
  <div>
    {this.state.data.map((ticket) => {
      return (
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            <div className="row align-items-center">
              <div className="col">
                <form className="row align-items-center">
                  <div className="col-auto pr-0">
                    <span className="fe fe-search text-muted" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col">
                    <input
                      type="search"
                      className="form-control form-control-flush search"
                      placeholder="Inngresa el #numero de ticket aqui..."
                    />
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* / .row */}
          </div>
          <div className="table-responsive">
            <table className="table table-sm table-nowrap card-table table-hover ">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox table-checkbox">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="custom-control-input"
                        name="ordersSelect"
                        id="ordersSelectAll"
                      />
                      <label
                        className="custom-control-label"
                        htmlFor="ordersSelectAll"
                      >
                        &nbsp;
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <th>N°: Ticket</th>
                  <th>Contrato</th>
                  <th>Empresa</th>
                  <th>Problema</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th colSpan={2}>Tecnico Asignado</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody className="list">
                <tr id={ticket._id}>
                  <td>
                    <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox table-checkbox">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="custom-control-input"
                        name="ordersSelect"
                        id="ordersSelectOne"
                      />
                      <label
                        className="custom-control-label"
                        htmlFor="ordersSelectOne"
                      >
                        &nbsp;
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td className="orders-order">
                    {'#' + ticket.ticketNumber}
                  </td>
                  <td className="orders-product">{ticket.contract.name}</td>
                  <td className="orders-date">
                    {ticket.contract.compant.name}
                  </td>
                  <td className="orders-total">{ticket.issue}</td>
                  <td className="orders-status">
                    <div className="badge badge-soft-info">
                      {ticket.status}
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td className="orders-method">
                    {ticket.assignedTechnical}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
)}
```

Como deberia hacer para seleccionar una fila de la tabla y que me muestre los datos en un modal?

Estuve probando multiples cosas y no lo puedo lograr

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer para obtener el ticket que ha seleccionado el usuario es setear un evento `onClick` (por ejemplo) y pasarle una función que reciba como parámetro el ticket, te pongo un ejemplo:

Para cuando hagan click en la fila:

```
 <tr id={ticket._id} onClick={() => this.handleRowClick(ticket)}>
```

Para ello tendrás que haber declarado en tu clase ese método de la misma manera que declaraste;

```
this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
this.handleRowClick = this.handleRowClick.bind(this);
```

Y en ese método manejas el ticket para lo que necesites después de que el usuario ha hecho click.

```
handleRowClick(ticket) {
  // Aqui realizas la lógica para abrir el modal pasándole el ticket seleccionado.
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Funciona a la bien. gracias Adolfo Onrubia